# How to deploy and run at a specific time Python scripts on Apache Spark?

Tags: python, python-2.7, deployment, apache-spark, pyspark

I have set of simple python 2.7 scripts. Also, I have set of linux nodes. I want to run at a specific time these scripts on these nodes.

Each script may work on each node. The script is not able to run on multiple nodes simultaneously.

So, I want to complete 3 simple tasks:

1. To deploy set of scripts.
2. To run at a specific time main script with specific parameters on any node.
3. To get result, when script is finished.

It seems, that I am able to complete first task. I have the following code snippet:

```
import urllib
import urlparse
from pyspark import SparkContext


def path2url(path):
    return urlparse.urljoin(
        'file:', urllib.pathname2url(path))

MASTER_URL = "spark://My-PC:7077"
deploy_zip_path = "deploy.zip"
sc = SparkContext(master=("%s" % MASTER_URL), appName="Job Submitter", pyFiles=[path2url("%s" % deploy_zip_path)])
```

But I have problems. This code immediately launches tasks. But I want just deploy scripts to all nodes.

Comment: This isn't really a spark-specific question -- you can use SCP and cron to do what you want.

Comment: @DavidGriffin, why do you think so? I think, that spark has pretty good task manager system, isn't it?

Comment: No it has no task management, not that I see at least. -- you can run jobs and get the results. But there is no scheduler, no way to say run this job at this time in the future unless you wrote that yourself. But why? Use something off the shelf like cron and ssh. Or, if you really need a robust solution, stand up Mesos and use something like Chronos

Comment: @DavidGriffin, I think, that cron is too small for my purpose. I have set of servers, I need to manage by all works against all servers. I believe, that I need more powerful tool. I will see on Mesos, thank you.

Comment: No worries -- you definitely want to look into the Mesos framework Chronos.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend keeping the code to deploy your PySpark scripts outside of your PySpark scripts.
2. [Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos) is a job scheduler that runs on Apache Mesos. Spark can run on Mesos. Chronos runs jobs as a shell command. So, you can run your scripts with any arguments you specify. You will need to deploy Spark and your scripts to Mesos nodes. Then, you can run submit your Spark scripts with Chronos using `spark-submit` as the command.
3. You would store your results by writing to some kind of storage mechanism within your PySpark scripts. Spark has support for text files, HDFS, Amazon S3, and more. If Spark doesn't support the storage mechanism you need, you can use an external library that does. For example, I write to Cassandra in my PySpark scripts using [cassandra-driver](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/).

Comment: Nice Answer! How can someone run PySpark on mesos(on VM) ?

Comment: @user3378649 Mostly has described in [Submitting Spark Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html). After you have a Mesos master setup on a VM, just point `spark-submit` to it using the `--master` argument.

Comment: but this is in case you need to run Scala/JAVA projects, I am reffering to Python version of Spark ?

Comment: My comment above is still the case. You provide a PySpark script as an argument to `spark-submit` instead of a main class and jar.